Remove selected value shadcn
Hello I am trying to make select value with an option to remove selected value but it doesn't work, select from shadcn/radix-ui.
I added everything on "SelectTrigger" and it is indeed visible, but triggers nothing, and also the select component still opens
it doesnt even trigger the console.log.
Added even z-51 but also didn't help
const Select = Root;

const SelectGroup = Group;

const SelectValue = Value;

const SelectTrigger = forwardRef<
  ElementRef<typeof Trigger>,
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Trigger> & {
    value?: string | null;
    onChange?: (value: string | null) => void;
  }
>(({ className, children, value, onChange, ...props }, ref) => {
  const handleClear = useCallback(
    (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
      console.log('triggered');
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      onChange?.('');
    },
    [onChange],
  );

  return (
    <Trigger
      ref={ref}
      dir="rtl"
      className={cn(
        'group z-[49] flex h-9 w-full items-center justify-between rounded-md border border-input bg-transparent p-4 text-sm shadow-sm ring-offset-background transition duration-200 placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus:outline-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50',
        className,
      )}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
      <div className="flex items-center gap-x-1">
        {value && onChange && (
          <Icon asChild>
            <X
              className="z-[51] h-4 w-4 shrink-0 cursor-pointer rounded-full opacity-0 transition-all duration-300 hover:bg-background hover:opacity-100 group-hover:opacity-50"
              onClick={handleClear}
            />
          </Icon>
        )}
        <Icon asChild>
          <RxCaretSort className="h-4 w-4 opacity-50" />
        </Icon>
      </div>
    </Trigger>
  );
});
SelectTrigger.displayName = Trigger.displayName;

const SelectContent = forwardRef<
  ElementRef<typeof Content>,
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Content>
>(({ className, children, position = 'popper', ...props }, ref) => (
  <Portal>
    <Content
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        'relative z-50 min-w-[8rem] overflow-hidden rounded-md border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow-md data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-0 data-[state=open]:fade-in-0 data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-95 data-[side=bottom]:slide-in-from-top-2 data-[side=left]:slide-in-from-right-2 data-[side=right]:slide-in-from-left-2 data-[side=top]:slide-in-from-bottom-2',
        position === 'popper' &&
          'data-[side=bottom]:translate-y-1 data-[side=left]:-translate-x-1 data-[side=right]:translate-x-1 data-[side=top]:-translate-y-1',
        className,
      )}
      position={position}
      {...props}
    >
      <Viewport
        className={cn(
          'p-1',
          position === 'popper' &&
            'h-[var(--radix-select-trigger-height)] w-full min-w-[var(--radix-select-trigger-width)]',
        )}
      >
        {children}
      </Viewport>
    </Content>
  </Portal>
));
SelectContent.displayName = Content.displayName;

const SelectLabel = forwardRef<
  ElementRef<typeof Label>,
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Label>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <Label
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('px-2 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold', className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
SelectLabel.displayName = Label.displayName;

